# добавить нули в данные

Tags: sql, sql-server

данные берутся из бд в которой обрезаются начальные нули

посоветуйте запрос для job, который бы подставлял недостающие начальные нули в таблицу
в столбце code данные должны содержать LEN(5) из 5 символов
то есть if Len < 5 добить вначале нулями ... к примеру login32 должен стать 06050

table1

```
user    code
login1  123
login3  12345
login7  78
login12 2304
login32 6050
login0  3
login33 3
```

Comment: `RIGHT('00000' + code, 5)`

Comment: благодарю, но коммент вроде нельзя поставить как ответ )

Comment: Да как бы... я вообще думал, что есть какие-то ещё заморочки, неозвученные, и ожидал коммента типа "это мне не подходит, потому что ...". А так ответ-то очевидный.

Comment: вообщем если хочешь доп очки к профилю можешь ответить - я заапрувлю ')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CONVERT (nvarchar(5), code)

RIGHT('00000' + code, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый метод:

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(n,3),' ','0')
```

В этого метожа есть преимущество, что он возвращает строку '***' для n < 0 или n > 999, что является хорошим и очевидным индикатором ввода за пределы. Другие методы, будут молча завершаться ошибкой, обрезая ввод до 3-символьной подстроки.

Второй метод:

Подходит для любой ситуации.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnNumPadLeft (@input INT, @pad tinyint)
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumStr VARCHAR(250)

    SET @NumStr = LTRIM(@input)

    IF(@pad > LEN(@NumStr))
        SET @NumStr = REPLICATE('0', @Pad - LEN(@NumStr)) + @NumStr;

    RETURN @NumStr;
END
```

Образец вывода:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fnNumPadLeft] (2016,10) -- returns 0000002016
SELECT [dbo].[fnNumPadLeft] (2016,5)  -- returns 02016
SELECT [dbo].[fnNumPadLeft] (2016,2)  -- returns 2016
SELECT [dbo].[fnNumPadLeft] (2016,0)  -- returns 2016
```